# New to GitHub - is there a way to get an overview of projects on it before unzipping and building?

Tags: android, github

I've been looking for a finished/working ImageView on Android that has pinch/zoom behavior.   Although there are code-snippets all over S.O. for this I want something a little more finished that I can just build and use.

GitHub, which I've never used before, seems to have candidates.   As far as I can tell GitHub is a free, public project-hosting, source-control system, but I'm only interested in downloading and trying out projects on it, which can be done by the "Download Zip" button on it.

I recently tried a project called PhotoView but after getting it all imported into my Eclipse development environment I found it had dependencies on a higher API level than I was using or targeting.

Is there any way to avoid that in the future?  I.e., is there any place on GitHub where the developers typically lists technical requirements like programming language, target development environment, compiler or SDK versions, etc, so before bothering to download a GitHub project I can guess whether it's even buildable in my environment?

**Edit:**  In my browser I can see a brief revision history but it looks like it only goes back a few changes so the manifest or other key files aren't always visible.  Is the only way to see the project files to download the ZIP file, unpack it and look at it in my development environment on my local PC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can actually browse the source on the site if you don't want to download the zip. Ideally the maintainer would have that kind of info in the readme, but that's not always there or complete.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to avoid that in the future?

Browse the source code. For example, the manifest file (for the component or a demo app) should indicate the `android:minSdkVersion`.

> is there any place on GitHub where the developers typically lists technical requirements like programming language, target development environment, compiler or SDK versions, etc, so before bothering to download a GitHub project I can guess whether it's even buildable in my environment?

Yes. It's called the project `README`, and you were already there, most likely, as it is the "home page" of the repository. The amount of documentation any given developer will write for any given component will vary.

You are also welcome to file issues against the project, asking for more documentation on this sort of thing, but if and when that issue will be acted upon will also vary.

Comment: Maybe I'm not asking this question in a basic enough way:  HOW do I browse the source code?   Do you mean download the project, unzip it and browse it on my PC?  Or is there a way to see it online?

Comment: @user316117: "HOW do I browse the source code?" -- um, it's right there in your Web browser. For example, visit https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts. You will see the top-level files/folders above the project README. Click on a folder to navigate into it; click on a file to view the contents.

Answer (score 0):

**readme** file in *root* of the project, and **Wikipages** of that repositories could help you  find out additional information about that repository. But at the end, contributors are responsible to prepare this kind of information and some of them don't care. So, you can look for Android manifest file of the project and check the content in GitHub website before download and unzip it.